# How to create panel like windows in WinForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, winforms, contextmenustrip

Please See this:

http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/2008/rolloversummaryschedule.jpg

How can i create a window that holds Patient data in it? The 2 records that you see is in List View. I would then using ContextMenuStrip for text "View Details". When View Details is clicked i need to show the context. For web development this could be done via Javascript,div and panels. How that should be WinForms?

Please Help.

Thanks!

Comment: Nagrani: Any reason you have tagged your question with asp.net, and contextmenustrip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- Make a form, formMaster, that displays the Schedule records in GridView
- Upon double click on a row event, display another form, formDetail, passing on the selected patient id
- Upon loading of the formDetail, get the patient record based upon that ID and set the controls accordingly.

Checkout:

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey.aspx)
- [How to: Create a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4.aspx)

**---EDIT--**

You can use the GroupBox, or the Panel control itself. Usually, with WinForms GroupBox is more of a common use.

- [Grouping Controls with the Windows Forms Panel Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984375%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)
- [Grouping Controls with the Windows Forms GroupBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984374%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But in terms of designing (& controls) what option is available in WinForms to design as shown in Image?

Comment: @Romil Nagrani: I see the image, but can you elaborate upon *what option is available in WinForms to design*? I dont understand. There is a separate toolbox to design the form.

Comment: For web based you have Panel to design the Box which displays information such as Patient Name, Notes etc. Which control(s) i have to used to design such in WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

I take it you mean as a popup panel, like you would see using javascript such as overlib (http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib/) - implementing this behaviour in winforms.

The way I have done this in the past is by having a user control which is an extended panel, and on the mouseenter event of the specific control I have shown the panel at the mouses's x,y coordinates, which are accessible from the event arguments in the handler.

Then on mouseleave you hide the usercontrol.